# ¿Qué diferencia había entre la grafía ſ y la s?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, historia, letras, alfabeto

En 1741, el abecedario del español se componía de la siguiente forma:

[image: Abecedario español]

Como se ve, la actual letra *s* minúscula se escribía entonces usando la grafía *ſ*. Sin embargo, había casos en los que sí se usaba la grafía *s* actual:

[image: Uso de la S]

Como se ve, se usaba *ſ* cuando va a principio de palabra o a mitad, pero a final se usa siempre la *s*. En algunos casos se podía duplicar la grafía *ſ*:

[image: S doble 1]

y en otros incluso se ponía una *ſ* y luego una *s*:

[image: S doble 2]

Otro ejemplo de este último grupo era la palabra *aſsí (así)*.

Así pues, ¿qué diferencia había entre ambas grafías? ¿Por qué no estaban ambas en el abecedario, sino sólo la *ſ*? ¿Se modificaba la pronunciación en los grupos *ſſ* y *ſs*?

(Todas las imágenes están tomadas de diferentes páginas de la [Orthographía española](http://www.rae.es/recursos/ortografia/primera-ortografia) de 1741.)

Comment: I am not sure if it answers your question precisely but does [this Wikipedia entry](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_larga) help?

Comment: @mdewey partially. I found that article after posting my question, and at least it says that the _ſ_ and the _s_ represent the same sound. But it does not say anything about the _ſs_ and the _ſſ_ groups.

Comment: Estaba buscando información sobre esto de la s larga (que no conocía antes de esta pregunta) y me he topado con [esto](https://books.google.es/books?id=vXIdbKyJYosC&pg=PA399&lpg=PA399&dq=escritura+%22s+larga%22&source=bl&ots=3eHkoiO-mU&sig=aFeZN0JpOTONJ1BRymj85PqzaUw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK1vyI2cHQAhWJtxQKHTaYBJoQ6AEIUjAN#v=onepage&q=escritura%20%22s%20larga%22&f=false). Supongo que la explicación será para el inglés aunque quizá podría servir también para el español. En otra parte he visto que se usaba la s y la f doble más por estética que otra cosa pero ya no encuentro el enlace.

Comment: @blonfu muy interesante el aporte. Creo que, como dice el artículo, en español la s larga no se usó más allá de finales del siglo XVIII. El diccionario de autoridades (de la primera mitad del siglo XVIII) usa la s larga, pero la siguiente edición, de 1780, ya no la usa. Sobre el grupo _ſs_, en las capturas se ve que se podía escribir tanto ese grupo como el _ſſ_.

Comment: Contestaré luego al tener acceso al ordenador y no en el móvil :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La ese en castellano tenía dos formas — y a veces más.  He aquí un fragmento de un libro con que estoy trabajando ahora (perdonadme que no puedo enlazároslo, porque no es de acceso abierto) que lleva *tres* formas distintas de la letra:

[image: Capit.vij.de los imenſos beneficios que fizo dios enſu encarnacion al linage humano.]

No obstante, a diferencia del alemán (donde la alternación entre *ſ* y *s* puede/podía indicar las fronteras entre elementos en una palabra compuesta), en el castellano, simplemente se seguía, más o menos, el modelo griego.  En esa escritura, la letra *Σ* tenía dos formas en minúscula, *σ* y *ς*.  La primera se utilizaba en toda posición *excepto* como letra final, y pues la segunda en esa posición última.  Así que la palabra por cerdo en griego, que se pronunciaría como *sus*, se escribía *σῦς*.  Pero puesto en mayúscula sería *ΣΥ͂Σ*.  La regla con letras latinas era parecida, con *ſ* siendo la forma principal, y *s* la forma en posición final.

Así la diferencia entre la *ſ* y *s* es, teóricamente, bastante simple y no muy diferente a la de entre *r* (después de letras con lado derecho recto y en posición inicial) y *ꝛ* (después de las con lado derecho redondo): son dos formas gráficas de una sola letra.

A veces, más por razones estéticas, se podía encontrar la forma *s* en el interior de una palabra, casi siempre después de la *ſ* cuando era debida una doble *s*.  En estos casos, y especialmente en letra cursiva, se podía encontrarlas ligadas, así que era frecuente ver *aſsi* escrito como *aßi*.

Y hablando de esa doble s... En el español no precisamente muy antiguo, había dos sonidos para la *S*, uno sonoro y otro sordo.  En posición inicial o final, tenía una pronunciación sorda, como la actual, pero entrevocálicamente, salía sonora, como la *Z* de inglés o portugués.   Para representar el sonido sordo entre vocales, se usaba dos S (así muy como la *R* en la ortografía moderna).  El portugués mantiene esta diferencia tanto en su ortografía como en su pronunciación y por eso tenemos *assim* y *seis* con sonidos sordos, pero *casa* con el valor sonoro.  Cuando el castellano perdió la distinción fonética (la fricativa alveolar sonora ya no existe en castellano como fonema, pero sigue como alófono), ya no había razón alguna por mantener la distinción ortografía, y se simplificó *ss* en *s*.

Answer (score 3):

La s larga era común a todos los idiomas de Europa occidental; derivaba de la caligrafía romana y medieval y se pronunciaba exactamente igual a la s que usamos en la actualidad; como dices, se usaba la s larga al comienzo y en medio del texto, mientras que al final se usaba la s corta, y también se usaban en conjunción la s larga y la corta (lo que derivó en la ligadura ß, o *eszett*, que aún se utiliza en alemán).
Es probable que la principal, aunque tal vez no la única, razón de su declive haya sido el desarrollo de la tipografía llamada "moderna": a fines del siglo XVIII, diseñadores tipográficos como Giambattista Bodoni y Firmin Didot comenzaron a descartar la s larga de sus diseños. Al ponerse estos de moda, la s larga terminó por desaparecer. En Inglaterra, por ejemplo, el impresor John Bell explicó, en una edición de Shakespeare de 1788, haber eliminado las s largas para evitar la confusión con la f y para que el texto pareciera más espaciado entre líneas (al no tener la s corta ascendentes como la s larga). Es muy probable que en España haya ocurrido lo mismo, al adoptarse los estilos tipográficos en boga y desaparecer la s larga de los tipos importados. El principal motivo por el que la s larga sobrevivió en Alemania es, seguramente, que los libros impresos en alemán, estaban, hasta no hace demasiado, compuestos mayormente en tipos góticos, que conservaron las características de la caligrafía.
[Aquí](http://typefoundry.blogspot.com.ar/2008/01/long-s.html) hay un detallado artículo (en inglés) que lo explica con más detalle.

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente tu respuesta, y desde luego el artículo que enlazas es muy interesante. Parece lógico que la desaparición de la _ſ_ fuera algo meramente tipográfico por cómo se parecía a la _f_. En todo caso, me falta por saber la parte de por qué en español se dieron las ligaduras _ſs_ y _ſſ_, por qué existían las dos y qué diferencia había entre ambas, si es que la había.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo creo que guifa lo ha respondido excelentemente, además de desasnarme respecto de que la s tenía dos sonidos en castellano, cosa que ignoraba.

Answer (score 0):

Históricamente la falta de correspondencia exacta entre fonología y ortografía llevó a muchos escribas del Medioevo a transcribir con "creatividad variada" los signos atribuibles a ciertos grafemas. Eso se hacía con el objeto de "acentuar" o adecuar ciertas pronunciaciones, por lo que es un error atribuir únicamente al mero acto decorativo la inclusión de alteraciones gráficas sobre algunos caracteres "estandarizados" de la época. La ſ no es la excepción, pues cuando está escrita con trazo izquierdo (asemejándose gráficamente a la f) su pronunciación es más aproximada a la conjunción "ts" o "tz", como es el caso de muchos toponímicos —en Francia y Alemania— que contienen ſ con trazo izquierdo y cuyas derivaciones onomásticas terminaron siendo transcriptas modernamente como tz, conservando esa pronunciación.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Spanish.SE. Es una magnífica respuesta, pero mejoraría si pudieras aportar alguna fuente o ejemplos para sustentarla. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Nunca he visto nada con respeto a eso de la diferencia entre ſ con o sin trazo izquierdo.  ¿Tienes alguna fuente?  Las pronunciaciones /ts/ y /dz/ se representaba en el español antiguo con *z*, *ç*.  No encuentro constancia de una variación de pronunciación entre *ſ*, *ſ con trazo izquierdo*, *s* tipo moderno, o *ς* estilo griego (las variantes gráficas que he encontrado en mi trabajo).  Lo único que conozco de este estilo sería la forma de ligar la *t* en escritura visigótica con otras letras, que dependía de que se pronunciaba como en latín o se debilitaba.