# ¿Cuál ha sido la evolución del abecedario español a lo largo del tiempo?

Tags: historia, alfabeto

En la primera [Orthographía española](http://www.rae.es/recursos/ortografia/primera-ortografia) de 1741, publicada por la RAE, nos encontramos con la siguiente disposición del abecedario español:

[image: Abecedario]

En esta imagen se nota la ausencia de algunas letras, siendo la más notable la de la Ñ, tratada previamente en [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18868/12637). Sin embargo, también se echan en falta otras como la CH y la LL, vigente hasta hace relativamente poco tiempo, y la W.

Sé que existen otras ortografías previas a esta, siendo algunas dignas de mención, como la [Ortografia kastellana, nueva i perfeta](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/%C3%8Dndice:Ortografia_kastellana,_nueva_i_perfeta.pdf) de 1630, que describe una ortografía totalmente fonética. Sin embargo, no sé si estas propusieron algún abecedario concreto, en cuyo caso me gustaría que se incluyeran en la respuesta.

Así pues, ¿cuál ha sido la evolución del abecedario español a lo largo del tiempo? ¿Cuándo tuvieron lugar las inclusiones y exclusiones de letras? ¿Qué abecedarios se propusieron antes de la llegada de la RAE?

Comment: Que curioso lo de la _Ortografia kastellana, nueva i perfeta_ Debía ser un punky el tal Gonzalo Correas Íñigo, está todo inventado

Comment: @blonfu ya te digo. Que los que escriben con _k_ se creerán unos _radikales_, pero de originales no tienen nada. :-)

Comment: Creía yo que "Abecedario" se traducía como "dictionary" y "alphabet" -> "Alfabeto". ¿No?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Por lo que he estado leyendo, casi todas las letras que conocemos o hemos conocido como parte del abecedario español (CH, LL, Ñ, RR, W), estaban reconocidas como *existentes* desde mediados del s. XVI o incluso antes; si bien, la RAE no quiso incluirlas en el alfabeto castellano por diversos motivos.
Por cierto, que esos y otros motivos (tanto para incluir, como para quitar letras, como para el resto de cambios que se han ido haciendo en la ortografía a lo largo de los años) suelen venir explicados con profundidad en los prólogos de los diccionarios, cosa que yo acabo de descubrir. Los prólogos de las ediciones de los ss. XVIII y XIX son de recomendadísima lectura.

#### Tratados no oficiales (s. XVI y XVII)

- En sus [*Reglas de Ortografía Española*](https://books.google.es/books?id=0bE-AQAAMAAJ&dq=ortografia%20antonio%20de%20nebrija&hl=es&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q&f=false), de 1512, Antonio de Nebrija propone el siguiente abecedario, que incluye la CH, la LL, la Ñ (aunque con tilde vertical) y la C con cedilla, pero excluye la K y la Q:

  > Aſsi que ſerà nueſtro A,B,C dèſtas veinte i ſeis letras proprias, i improprias. **A, B, C, ç, CH, D, E*, F, G, H, I Vocal, Y Conſonante, L ſencilla, LL doblada, M, N ſin titulo, Ń con titulo, O, P, R, S, T, U Vocal, V Conſonante, X, Z** : porque a la K i a la Q ninguno le queda ni proprio ni improprio : pues que por la C ſe puede ſuplir aquello de que agora ſirven.

<sub>* La E no aparece en esa página del libro original por error de imprenta. La incluyo yo para completar las 26 letras mencionadas.</sub>

- Mateo Alemán, en su [*Ortografía castellana*](https://books.google.es/books?id=yRNmAAAAcAAJ&dq=ortographia&hl=es&pg=PA43-IA1#v=onepage&q&f=false) de 1609, reintroduce la Q, propone nuevos símbolos para los sonidos de la CH y la R suave, y mantiene la S "alta" y la C con cedilla:

  > **a b ç d e f g h ↄ i c l ll m n ñ o p q r ꝛ ſ s t v u x y z**
- Mientras que en la [Ortografia kastellana, nueva i perfeta](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina:Ortografia_kastellana,_nueva_i_perfeta.pdf/25) de 1630, Gonzalo Korreas considera innecesarios muchos de esos símbolos y propone en cambio esta simplificación:

  > **a b c d e f g h i k l m n o p q r s t v x y z**

#### Tratados oficiales de la RAE (s. XVIII)

- En la *Ortographia* de 1741, la primera editada por la RAE y la que toma como base la pregunta, el abecedario se establece oficialmente como muestra la imagen:

  > **A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V X Y Z**
- Pero ya en la [Ortografía de 1754](https://books.google.es/books?id=f89MAAAAcAAJ&dq=ortografia%201754&hl=es&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false), es decir la siguiente edición a la mencionada, se vuelven a incluir de manera oficial en el abecedario las letras CH, LL y Ñ omitidas en la edición anterior:

  > En la primera impreſion de eſte Tratado ſe dexaron de añadir la *ch*, la *ll* y la *ñ* que ſon letras propias nueſtras; pero ahora, reflexionando eſte punto, ha parecido que ſin ellas eſta defectuoſo el Abecedario [...] De modo que el Abecedario Caſtellano completo conſta de veinte y ocho Letras y ſon por eſte orden:
  >   **a. b. c. ch. d. e. f. g. h. i. j. k. l. ll. m. n. ñ. o. p. q. r. s. t. u. v. x. y. z.**

#### Cambios recientes (s. XX)

- No fue hasta 1969, más de 200 años después, que se incluyó la **W** en la *Ortografía* (y, al año siguiente, en el *Diccionario*). No tengo enlace a las obras originales de la RAE porque siguen manteniendo la propiedad intelectual (supongo), pero sí a un [tratado sobre el tema](https://books.google.es/books?id=KTtBAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA384&dq=ortograf%C3%ADa%20%201974&hl=es&pg=PA210#v=snippet&q=uve%20doble&f=false):

  > [...] la Academia la incluye en el alfabeto como letra propia en la *Ortografía* de 1969. Así, en el *Diccionario* editado un año después podemos leer: «Vigésima sexta letra del abecedario español y vigésima primera de sus consonantes. Su nombre es *uve doble* [...]»
- Finalmente, [en 1994 se acordó despojar a las letras CH y LL de su categoría de letra](http://www.rae.es/consultas/exclusion-de-ch-y-ll-del-abecedario), 240 años después de serles reconocida; aunque no fue [hasta 2014](https://www.google.es/search?q=eliminacion%20de%20ch%20y%20ll) que se reflejó este cambio en la normativa. Con lo que llegamos al abecedario actual, similar al de 1741 salvo por incluir la Ñ y la W:

  > **A B C D E F G H I J K L M N Ñ O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z**

<sub>Nota: de la RR, no encuentro ninguna fuente que la incluya como letra distinta de la R. Aunque recuerdo que en mi colegio nos la enseñaban como parte del abecedario (*... O, P, Q, R, **RR**, S, T, U...*), todos los tratados y ediciones que he consultado, si la mencionan, es únicamente para aclarar que *no* corresponde contarla aparte.</sub>

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu dedicación! Me ha llamado la atención el hecho de que en 1609 se distinguieran las letras _ʃ_ y _s_, cosa que ya se trató de refilón [en otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18880/12637).